# Stack buffer overflow using return addresses

Tags: c, memory, stack, buffer-overflow

I am really confused with the stack buffer overflow exploit using return addresses.

In my understanding, a stack frame looks like this:
-return address
-arguments
-- Here you jump to an address in code memory, base pointer get's value of current stack pointer
i.e. end of arguments memory address
-local variables

these first two get done by the 'call' instruction in assembly.

but if the local variables section is lower memory than the return address, how can you modify the return address by let's say:

```
char* local_variable[10]
// command_arg is larger than 10 ? with some return address after that
strcp(local_variable, command_arg)
```

In my understanding, this could never edit the return address it lies higher in the stack than the value at local_variable address, which will grow down when copied to.

I am using Kali-Linux 2021.4a 64 bit

Any insight is appreciated.

Comment: Google "how do buffer overflow attacks work". There are many websites with memory diagrams that show it.

Comment: E.g. https://www.coengoedegebure.com/buffer-overflow-attacks-explained/

Answer (score 0):

after taking a look at the folowing link, I found the simple answer.

Apparantly this previously called local variables section is called the buffer, a stack frame lies in the following structure:

- arguments - return address - saved previous base pointer (wich is replaced by the current stack pointer) - buffer

https://www.coengoedegebure.com/buffer-overflow-attacks-explained/

Though with the information I had first, it indeed seems like the buffer will grow down when strcp(local_variablem, command_arg), not being able to reach the return address.

Well apparently the buffer section grows upwards so it can overwrite the return address.